# django partial search issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

This sample text that needs to be searched

State Model

```json
    {
        "region": "National Capital Territory of Delhi",
        "country": "in"
    },
    {
        "region": "Union Territory of Chandigarh",
        "country": "in"
    },
```

I have two models on the server, First is a country model in which user selects the country they reside in then from that state is filter and is displayed.

So now if they type `Chandigarh` when am using they query

```py
state = loginModels.State.objects.filter(country=country_code.lower()).filter(region__icontains=state).get()
```

It automatically selects -> `Union Territory of Chandigarh`

BUT,

Now if the user types `NCT of Delhi` the above query fails I tried `Q` method too as suggested in blogs, this also FAILS.

```py
state = loginModels.State.objects.filter(country=country_code.lower()).filter(Q(region__icontains=query)).get()
```

**P.S**
Note In this user stands for the system, so backend system calls like `NCT` and above query fails in several places we don't want to hardcode places.

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting only one result to be returned?  .get() will get the first item in a query always.  If you want a list of more than one state, then remove .get() and just use .filter()

Comment: @ja408 yes am expecting only one object to be returned, and even if I remove .get() and just use .filter() then also there is no object returned.

Comment: I have also tried ````SearchVectorField```` of Postgres search on ````region```` field but still the same.